# Display query result in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query with over 50 return results. Now I need to display the results in a table with 3 rows and 3 columns.

Something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                                        
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                                        
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                                        
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried it with PHP like this:

```
$q = "SELECT name, address, content FROM mytable"; 
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $name   = $row['name'];
    $address = $row['address'];
    $content = $row['content'];

    //Create new output
    $output  = "<p>$name</p>";
    $output .= "<p>$address</p>";
    $output .= "<p>$content</p>";

    //Add output to array
    $mycontent[] = $output;     
}
```

Then I am printing the content array in my table like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $mycontent[0]; ?></td>                   
    <td><?php echo $mycontent[1]; ?></td>                   
    <td><?php echo $mycontent[2]; ?></td>                   
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $mycontent[3]; ?></td>                   
    <td><?php echo $mycontent[4]; ?></td>                   
    <td><?php echo $mycontent[5]; ?></td>                                       
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $mycontent[6]; ?></td>                   
    <td><?php echo $mycontent[7]; ?></td>                   
    <td><?php echo $mycontent[8]; ?></td>                                           
</tr>
```

Using this code, I can only display 9 contents. My problem is that I want to display more content. I'm going to use [pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) to display contents; something like 0-9, 10-18, 19-27 etc.

> NOTE: I can do the pagination part.

I hope someone will give me the right direction for this.

Thank you.

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 3):

try something like:

```
 echo "<table>";
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 $name   = $row['name'];
 $address = $row['address'];
 $content = $row['content'];
 echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td><td>".$address."</td><td>".$content."</td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

this example will print in table all the result of the query.
if you want to limit only to some results, so limit the sql query. 
for example:

```
 $q = "SELECT name, address, content FROM mytable limit 50";
```

to get each content,name, address in TD, and 3 of mycontent(content, name, address) in a TR try this:

```
$c= mysql_query("select COUNT(name) from mytable");
$n=mysql_fetch_array($c);
$maxname= $n[0];
$i=0;
$tr=0;
echo "<table>";
while ($tr < $maxname)
{ 
echo "<tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC) and $i<$tr) {
$name   = $row['name'];
$address = $row['address'];
$content = $row['content'];
echo "<td>".$name." | ".$address." | ".$content."</td>";
$i++;
}
echo "</tr>";
$tr= $tr+3;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: name, address and content should be place in one td not in 3 td

Comment: you mean you the the table like this:
each custermer in <td> , and 3 custermers in each <tr>?

Comment: @TNK i edited my answer to have name, address and content in 1 TD.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. It places your values in an easy to use associative array. Then you just loop through.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $values[] = array(
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'address' => $row['address'],
        'content' => $row['content']
    );
}
?>
<table>
<?php
foreach($values as $v){
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$v['name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$v['address'].'</td>
        <td>'.$v['content'].'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `for`-loop to iterate your `$mycontent`-array:

EDIT: I was made aware that `$mycontent` is built differently than I first assumed:

```
$h = "<table>"; // we are going to build the table in $h

$maxcount = count($mycontent); // get the number of values within the array 

for ($i = 0;$i < $maxcount;$i++) { // counting $i up from 0 to $maxcount -1 ...

   $h.= "<tr><td>{$mycontent[$i]}</td></tr>"; // build row

}

$h.= "</table>"; // close the table
echo $h; // echo it
```

---> live demo: http://3v4l.org/g1E1T

Comment: I am little confuse about your code. Can you kindly explain it bit?

Comment: Why use a `for` loop when you can iterate result using `while`?

Comment: This wont work because you missed how he built $mycontent... Its not an array of objects... its a literal string. 
i.e. $mycontent[0] = "<p>John Doe</p><p>101 Lost st</p><p>something</p>"

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk: I wanted to continue working with $mycontent. Of course, you could write the table from within the `while`.

Comment: With your edited code my output is 1 row and 1 td. Its not my expecting result

Comment: @TNK: sorry, change `$maxcount=count($output);` to`$maxcount=count($mycontent);`

Answer (score 0):

You can store in a variable if u r planning to use it in a function or you can just print it. Either way...

```
$q = "SELECT name, address, content FROM mytable"; 
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q); 

$str = "<table>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $str .= "<tr>";
    $str .= "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    $str .= "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
    $str .= "<td>" . $row['content'] . "</td>";
    $str .= "</tr>";
}

$str .= "</table>"

echo $str;
```

There you go!

Comment: Just call this piece of code. It will create the whole table for you.

Comment: name, address and content should be place in one td not in 3 td

Comment: Well, you can tweak it yourself.. get creative.. Its extremely simple at this point. You shouldn't be needing anymore help.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN REFERENCE THIS CODE

```
             <tbody>
              <!-- <tr>
                <td>Technology</td>
                <td>Professor Abiola</td>
                <td>wetech@school.com</td>
                <td> Plot 2, Oriola road,</td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Edit</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
              </tr> -->
              <?php 
                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
                 $faculty = $rows['faculty'];
                  $hod = $rows['hod'];
                  $email = $rows['email']; 
                  // $location = $rows['location'];
                echo "<tr>
                        <td>$faculty</td>
                        <td>$hod</td>
                        <td>$email</td>
                        <td>".$rows["location"]."</td>
                        <td>
                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Edit</button>
                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Update</button>
                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>
                        </td>

                       </tr>";
                }
              
              ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Please explain how this code can be helpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).